# Multiply values in object and assign to new array objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array object and i have use map to multiply over each value

Myobject :

```
[{key: "Labour Cost", value: "118"}, {key: "Transport Cost", value: "118"}, {key: "Material Cost", value: "118"}]
```

function to calculate and merge as key value pair

```
const calculate = (elementID, i) => {
let mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
if (mainRow != null) {
  let qty = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[name=quantity]')[0].value;
  row[i].costRow.map((vl) => {
    const multiplyResult = qty * vl.value;
    object = Object.assign({}, {vl[key]: multiplyResult}); // **getting error here**
    
  });
  console.log(object);
}
}
```

Expected output :

```
[{key: "Labour Cost", value: "1146"}, {key: "Transport Cost", value: "123"}, {key: "Material Cost", value: "2334"}]
```

Comment: Could you please include the relevant HTML in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Since *key* is not a variable (object property) you can try the following:

```
object = Object.assign({}, {[vl['key']]: multiplyResult});
```

**Note:** Since you are not returning anything from `.map()` you can use `.forEach()`.